# Google Apps Script: check the referring URL of the request (standalone web app)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

I'd like to perform a check on the referring URL of a (standalone, anonymous) Google Apps Script, and take some action if the referring URL is one of two known "good" URLs.

Is there a way to do this? The best I've come up with so far involves client-side code and unfortunately `document.referrer` always begins `https://script.google.com`, not the address of the page with the link to the Google Apps script:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.heading = "My heading"
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
}

function validReferrer(ref) {
  Logger.log("Referrer is: "+ref)
  if (ref.indexOf('my-good-url.com') > - 1 ) {
    return true
}
else 
  return false
}
```

index.html

```
<div>
<script>
  function onSuccess(a) {
  alert(a);
  }
  // referrer always begins https://script.google.com
  var ref = document.referrer || "doesn't have a referrer"; 
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
  .validReferrer(ref)
</script>

<h1><?= heading ?></h1>
</div>
```

Ideally I'd like to run the check purely on the server side. As stated on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) "*for security reasons, content returned by the Content service isn't served from script.google.com, but instead redirected to a one-time URL at script.googleusercontent.com*" — and this is certainly confirmed by my findings. Interestingly when I change the sandbox mode to `NATIVE`, a referrer is not returned at all. I guess caja is filtering my client-side code.

The real referring page begins `http://` (confirmed in my browser's web debugger console by issuing `document.referrer`).

Comment: I can confirm that NATIVE doesn't allow `document.referrer`, and that with IFRAME, `document.referrer` does not return the referrer, but the URL of the Apps Script App.

Comment: If you control the sites that you have approved for calling the Apps Script, you could put some verification code in the URL search string maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately I only have very limited control over the sites' URLs :(